# adding a magento page to the catalog

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I want to add another page in the magento module like the following...

```
<catalog_wizard_default translate="label">
  <reference name="content">
   <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.topnav" template="catalog/navigation/top.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml"/>
  </reference>
 </catalog_wizard_default>
```

so when customer types in the url, they can do it like so

domain.com/catalog/wizard. I have no idea how to do this. I tried adding another action in the catalog controller like the following

```
  public function wizardAction(){
  $this->renderLayout();
 }
```

But this doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I think you need to call $this->loadLayout() before you render the layout...

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a layout handle of `catalog_wizard_default` will translate into the following Module-Controller-Action path: `Mage_Catalog` - `WizardController` - `defaultAction()`.

I would suggest that you need to follow these [instructions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller) to copy `CategoryController` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/controllers` and add an action called wizardAction().  Your layout will then be called `<catalog_category_wizard>`.

Unfortunately overriding/extended core controllers is quite complicated in Magento, so make sure you follow the wiki instructions carefully.

Hope this helps.
JD